# How to enlarge a filter?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Consider a filter $\mathcal{F}$ on a set $X$, and some subset $E\subseteq X$ such that neither $E$ nor $X-E$ are in $\mathcal{F}$.

On page 103 of "Handbook of Analysis and Its Foundations" the author claims that the collection $\mathcal{C}=\{F\cap L:F\in \mathcal{F}\;\mbox{and}\; E\subseteq L\subseteq X\}$ is a filter containing $\mathcal{F}\cup\{E\}$.

I am stuck at showing that if $C\in\mathcal{C}$ and $C\subseteq S$ then $S\in\mathcal{C}$. How is this accomplished? I feel $\mathcal{C}$ is missing sets needed for this to be true.

The reason I say this is that $\mathcal{L}=\mathcal{F}\cup\{E\}$ has the finite intersection property, and the smallest filter containing $\mathcal{L}$ is

$$\mathcal{L}^{*}=\{S\subseteq X: S\supseteq L_{1}\cap\ldots\cap L_{n} \;\mbox{for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $L_{1},\ldots,L_{n}\in\mathcal{L}$}\},$$

which appears to contain more sets than $\mathcal{C}$.

---

Edit: I was incorrect, and $\mathcal{C}$ has enough sets to be a filter and it equals $\mathcal{L}^{*}$. indeed, if $C\in\mathcal{C}$ and $C\subseteq S$, then $C=F\cap L$ for some $F\in\mathcal{F}$ and $E\subseteq L$. Then $F\cup S\in\mathcal{F}$, and if we let $\hat{F}=F\cup S$ and $\hat{L}=S\cup L$ then $S=\hat{F}\cap\hat{L}$ with $\hat{F}\in\mathcal{F}$ and $E\subseteq\hat{L}$. So $\mathcal{C}$ is a filter, and clearly $\mathcal{L}^{*}=\mathcal{C}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But if $C=F_0\cap L_0$ where $F_0 \in \mathcal{F}$ and $E\subseteq L_0$, then $\hat{F}:=(S\cap L_0)\cup(F_0\setminus L_0)\cup (S\setminus L_0)$ is in $\mathcal{F}$. And then $\hat{L}:= (S\setminus L_0) \cup L_0$ satisfies $E\subseteq \hat{L}$, while $S=\hat{F}\cap \hat{L}$.

Why do you think the filter conatining $\mathcal{L}$ has more sets?

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean $F_{0}$ in the second term of definition of $\hat{F}$? Also, if I take $S=E$ then $S\cap L_{0}=E$, which is not in $\mathcal{F}$, so I don't see why $\hat{F}\in F$.

Comment: For the first question, yes. I just made a typo.To the second question, $\hat{F}\in \mathcal{F}$ as soon as $F_0\subseteq \hat{F}$, since $\mathcal{F}$ is closed upwards. As soon as $E \supseteq (S\cap L_0)\cup (F_0\setminus)\supseteq F_0$, you know that $E\in \mathcal{F}$.